# Node express Json Web Token- how to handle invalid token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

```
const token = req.headers[process.env.AUTH_KEY_NAME];
    if (!token) return res.send("No token provided").status(401);

    try {
      const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
      return res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (e) {
      return res.send(e).status(401);
    }
  },
```

This is the code I use to handle token validation. There are 3 possibilities: no token, wrong token and correct token provided. Everything is called when it supposed to, however when the token is incorrect i get an error in console 'JsonWebTokenError: invalid token', that is correct but it also crashes the app. How do I prevent the app from crashing? Here is other code I found that also crashes app with invalid token

```
const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, (err, payload) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err).status(401);
      }
    });
    return res.status(200).json(user);
```

Comment: The code in your first code block works perfectly fine for me

Comment: I think you need to call `status()` before `send()`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crash"?

Comment: @MichaelM. did you test the code with all 3 scenarios?

Comment: @Quentin by crashing I mean throwing error that stop the program from running/listening and I need to restart it.

Comment: @Dzero Yes I've tested all three scenarios and nothing throws an error on my machine. Can you provide the exact package name and version of your JWT library from your `package.json`?

Comment: @MichaelM. "express": "^4.18.2", "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",

Comment: i think you could use a middleware on your routes to check for the token validity

Answer (score -1):

Use the callback function to prevent the app from crashing.

```
var tokenData;
jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, (err, data) => {
  data && (tokenData = data);
});
if (!tokenData) {
  throw new Error("==> Token expired");
}
```

I think this will work.

Comment: I used in the second example of code callback function. Just to be sure I tested this code and exactly the same problem, with invalid token provided i get the error JsonWebTokenError: invalid token and crashes the app.